# Fragment Layout Update only once possible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments. The content of the second fragment depends on the user input of the first one.

So if the user puts a 0 in the first fragment, I want to show the first LinearLayout, if he puts 1 I want to show the second LinearLayout. Both LinearLayouts are in the same xml-file.

My code works (see below). However it only works ONCE. On the first call it does everything it is supposed to. But on all the following calls, the setVisibility command does not seem to work anymore (at the same time the console prints work without problem).

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position+1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("test"+unitOfMeasurement);
        View rootView;
        View unitView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personalization_unit, container, false);
        View boundaryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personalization_low, container, false);
        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:
            rootView = unitView;
        break;
        case 2:
            rootView = boundaryView;
        break;
        default:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personalization_dummy, container, false);
        }

        setupUnitClickListener(unitView, boundaryView);
        setupInputFields(boundaryView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupInputFields(View view) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mmol_low_picker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mgdl_low_picker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(unitOfMeasurement==1) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mmol_low_picker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("mmol gone");
        } else if(unitOfMeasurement==0) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mgdl_low_picker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("mgdl gone");
        }

        /*switch(unitOfMeasurement) {
        case 0: //it's mmol/l
            view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mgdl_low_picker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final EditText val1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_low_mmol_value1);
            final EditText val2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_low_mmol_value2);
            System.out.println("testtt");
        break;
        case 1: //it's mg/dl
            LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_mgdl_low_picker);
            lin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final EditText val3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_low_mgdl_value1);
            System.out.println("gettinasd here"+unitOfMeasurement);
        break;
        }*/
    }

    private void setupUnitClickListener(View view, final View boundaryView) {
        final TextView mmoll = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_unit_option1);
        final TextView mgdl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_personalization_unit_option2);

        if(unitOfMeasurement==0) { //using mmol
            mmoll.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#920d0a"));
            mmoll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#44525252"));
            mgdl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#525252"));
            mgdl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        } else { //using mg/dl
            mgdl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#920d0a"));
            mgdl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#44525252"));
            mmoll.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#525252"));
            mmoll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        }

        mmoll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mmoll.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#920d0a"));
                mmoll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#44525252"));
                mgdl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#525252"));
                mgdl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                unitOfMeasurement = 0;
            }
        });

        mgdl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mgdl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#920d0a"));
                mgdl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#44525252"));
                mmoll.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#525252"));
                mmoll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
                unitOfMeasurement = 1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry about the messy code, I also tried the other way round (setting all visibilities to gone and then show one). Everything does not work anymore after the first call.

EDIT: Added entire code. All of it, except the dummyclass was created by the Android SDK.

Comment: if you really use fragment then please read more about the life cycle of it, as far i can't understand anything from your code. I don't see any fragment except visualize/unvisualize some view.

Comment: I added the entire code. The function that works only once is setupInputFields. Now the goal is, that the right view is shown when you swipe from fragment one to fragment two.

Comment: I only see one path to the code you're having trouble with, and its called through onCreateView. Are you expecting the visibility to toggle on some other event?

Comment: No. It's only called there. Isn't oncreateview called every time you swipe?

Comment: yes, just making sure u weren't expecting it to toggle when the user clicks buttons.   Anyways, rootview is set to boundary view only in "case 2."  I'd put some log messages in the switch, and make sure case 2 is being called.

Comment: this isn't the problem. The view is displayed. But within the view I have my two different linearlayouts I try to make visible in setupInputFields. This function is called no matter what case.

Comment: the function may be called in any case, but the rootview is only set to boundaryview in one case, and this is returned as the view to draw in only one case as well.

Comment: at any rate, try putting your two linear layouts in the same xml, or inflating them alternatively.  You're returning only one of several views that you're inflating, and likely leaving them to compete for who's on top, which is probably being affected by which one is selected to be the rootview in the swtich.